# Correlation bounds on transformations of two random variables

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, copula

Suppose I have 3 real-valued random variables, $X, Y, Z$ and their pairwise correlations, $\rho_{XY}, \rho_{YZ}, \rho_{XZ}$, and I am tasked with finding a 2d function $f$ such that $f(X,Y)$ has higher correlation with $Z$ than either $X$ or $Y$ alone. That is, $f$ should be such that $\rho_{f(X,Y),Z} > \rho_{X,Z}$ and $\rho_{f(X,Y),Z} > \rho_{Y,Z}$.

My question is: is there a way to bound the maximum possible correlation between $f(X,Y)$ and $Z$? My intuition is that this should be limited by the correlation between $X,Y$ and $Y,Z$, and I wonder if there are any results along these lines.

Comment: I think you are getting at something interesting, but you may need more restrictions. As such I might just suppose the existence of $f : X(\omega) \times Y(\omega) \mapsto Z(\omega)$, thus I can choose to obtain $f(X,Y) = Z$ resulting in the foregone conclusion of $\rho_{f(X,Y),Z} = 1$.

Comment: What is $\omega$ here?

Comment: $\omega$ is an element of the outcome space $\Omega$ used to construct the $\Sigma$-algebra for which those variables are measurable. It is just to say that without further restrictions added, we can pair the values of these variables together in anyway we like. Thus we can achieve the less interesting case of pairing things to exactly equal $Z$.

Comment: @Galen The flaw in your analysis is that your equation doesn't necessarily define a function.  When there exist outcomes $\omega$ and $\eta$ for which $X(\omega)=X(\eta)=x$ (say) and $Y(\omega)=Y(\eta)=y$ (say) but $Z(\omega)\ne Z(\eta),$ you are stating that $f(x,y)$ has two distinct values.

Comment: Surgical: to see the problem with your intuition, consider a continuous random variable $Z$ and suppose $X = Z$ when $|Z|\le 1$ and otherwise $X = -Z.$ Depending on the distribution of $Z$, the correlation of $(X,Z)$ can have any value between $-1$ and $1.$  But the transformation $f(X,Y)=-|X|$ has correlation $-1$ with $Z$ and the transformation $f(X,Y)=|X|$ has correlation $+1$ with $Z.$

Comment: @whuber Your description of functions is true, and points out that I made the point sloppily in terms of equality of random variables, but it missed the point of my analysis. The possible existence of such functions prevents any fully general upper bound less than +1. It is a corner case, sure, but its existence falsifies the original claim.

Comment: @Galen I see; thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with $\Sigma$-algebras as I should be, so perhaps this is naive, but I don't see how we could have $f: X(\omega) \times Y(\omega) \rightarrow Z(\omega)$. 

Let's suppose I have two sets of draws from these random variables, $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2,  y_2, z_2)$. How can I be guaranteed that a function $f$ exists satisfying both $f(x_1, y_1) = z_1$ and $f(x_2, y_2) = z_2$? For example, suppose that in this particular random draw, $x_1 = x_2$, $y_1 = y_2$, but $z_1 \neq z_2$. Then I'd have a contradiction.

Comment: @SurgicalCommander As whuber rightly emphasized, you can easily have such non-functions. It is rather common in practice that we cannot assume a function. Rather, your setup in the original post does not preclude the existence of such cases where a function always gives the equality $f(x_i, y_i) = z_i$, yielding perfect correlation. The issue is not that the counter-example to what you wish to prove is universal, but rather that any counter-example to what you wish to prove is a refutation of what you wish to prove.